# Search Spotlight for a file of specific type between two dates

Tags: macos, spotlight

I've had a hard time tracking down a way to search for documents of a specific type between two dates in Spotlight. Maybe it's not possible? I'd like to be able to type something like this in Spotlight:

`kind:pages modified:>151120&<=151126`

Which would then return Pages documents modified between November 21st and 26th, 2015. I've tried various date formats and searching for (Spotlight) alternatives, but no luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date format needs to be same as the one that you set in `system preference`

[image]

If your date format is same as the screenshot attached, then the search will become:

`kind:pages modified:>11/20/15 modified:<=11/26/15`

Otherwise, you'll need to change the date format to the one that you have set in your `Language & Region` (screenshot)